# How to sort itertools.combinations results by descending

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and want to find all possible combinations, I'm using below code

```
from itertools import combinations

cols=['AA','XY','GH','SD','DT']
col_comb =list()

for n in range(2,len(cols)+1):
    col_comb += list(combinations(cols,n))

print (col_comb)
```

I want to sort the output combination of above in descending order of number of elements, expected output like this,

`[('AA', 'XY', 'GH', 'SD', 'DT'),('AA', 'XY', 'GH', 'SD'), ('AA', 'XY', 'GH', 'DT'), ('AA', 'XY', 'SD', 'DT'), ('AA', 'GH', 'SD', 'DT'), ('XY', 'GH', 'SD', 'DT'),('AA', 'XY', 'GH'), ('AA', 'XY', 'SD'), ('AA', 'XY', 'DT'), ('AA', 'GH', 'SD'), ('AA', 'GH', 'DT'), ('AA', 'SD', 'DT'), ('XY', 'GH', 'SD'), ('XY', 'GH', 'DT'), ('XY', 'SD', 'DT'), ('GH', 'SD', 'DT'),('AA', 'XY'), ('AA', 'GH'), ('AA', 'SD'), ('AA', 'DT'), ('XY', 'GH'), ('XY', 'SD'), ('XY', 'DT'), ('GH', 'SD'), ('GH', 'DT'), ('SD', 'DT')]`

Comment: Reversing your range like this `range(len(cols)+1, 1, -1)` should work just fine

Comment: @PietroD'Antuono: You need to remove the `+ 1` when you reverse the arguments (I'm not a huge fan of writing `range`s that directly iterate in reverse because people mess that up all the time; reversing a forward `range` with `reversed` or `[::-1]` is usually more clear).

Comment: @ShadowRanger namely you are perfectly right. In my comment I just wanted to show what is the minimum amount of change required to that piece of code to make it work. To do so, I used the fact that `itertools.combinations` returns an empty list `if n>len(cols)`. I also agree with your readability suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse your `range` to make it start from the largest `n`:

```
for n in range(2,len(cols)+1)[::-1]:
# or
for n in reversed(range(2,len(cols)+1)):
# or
for n in range(len(cols), 1, -1):
```

All of the above are essentially identical, performance-wise, on Python 3, so choose the one that looks nicest to you.

Side-note: As `cols` increases, this will blow your memory; you *really* don't want to be writing code that holds *all* the results of multiple calls to `combinations` unless you're 100% sure the inputs will always be small. You can and should `print` the results as you generate them, never `list`ifying a single `combinations`, rather than accumulating them all in a `list` and `print`ing that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the sorted function with as key the length of the tuple

```
from itertools import combinations

cols=['AA','XY','GH','SD','DT']
col_comb =list()

for n in range(2,len(cols)+1):
    col_comb += list(combinations(cols,n))


sorted(col_comb,key=lambda x:len(x))
print (col_comb)
 `
```

Comment: You'd need to reverse too `reverse=True`. And use `.sort` as `sorted()` will return a copy rather than editing `col_comb`

Comment: `lambda x:len(x)` is the same as `len`. There is no point in making a named function anonymous.